# IIS 7 - worker processes more than one

Tags: iis-7, application-pools, worker-process, iis

if i set worker process as 1, my application pool hangs.
if i set it at least 6, everything works fine.

but every article i read says "don't set it more than 1"

so, in this practice, am i wrong? or who is wrong?

of course i would like to use less memory, cpu.
and another reason i hate about more worker process is sessions.
it is really annoying me.

the site that runs under the app pool has more than 20.000 online visitors
i tried to debug dump files but found nothing interesting

please give me some advice.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, the low-N number is hanging due to a race condition in your code somewhere.

With MaxProcesses=6, you're reducing the level of in-process concurrency, by sending fewer requests to more worker processes.

To debug the original cause:

- Configure for 1 worker process
- Wait for a hang - you might want to enable OrphanWorkerProcess for the App Pool in order to leave the hung w3wp in memory after it gets recycled

  - it presumably does get recycled when it hangs, right? Fails a ping, marked unresponsive, events in the Application and System event logs?
- Grab a memory dump of the process while it's in the hung state
- Feed that dump into DebugDiag 1.2 and see what it suggests

How did you get the memory dump? (as a rule, you must use a debugger of the same bitness as the worker process to get useful information from it).

Comment: Thank you TristanK, i used DebugDiag. I will do step-by-step liek you said. This time i will make sure Orphan is enabled. And i will share the results.

Comment: it hanged 2 times after set worker process to 1. then i recycled it and it works again. once an hour it hangs. i realized that, in event log i see "schannel error". after a couple of minutes iis hangs. do you have any idea on this issue? here is the event log message 
The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

Comment: Suggest trying the original plan as a first step.